# Micro Second Issue in Informatica

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Greetings!!

One of my source table(oracle) date column having the value 5/3/2013 6:00:51.134000000 AM. I am trying to pull the same into to my target(oracle), 
but my target converted the micro seconds as "zeros" and loading the value 5/3/2013 06.00.51.000000000 AM. 
Both my source & target column has declared as timestamp. I have set the date format like MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.US in session properties

Can anyone help to me to get the date with micro seconds? I am using informatica 10.2.0 Thx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way to resolve this is to increase the precision of the source or target definition to precision 29 and scale 9 after the source/target is imported into Informatica. This will handle the digits in milliseconds without converting them to all zeros. Plz check below link 
http://www.raghavatal.com/2014/06/05/how-to-handle-high-precision-dates-in-informatica-the-ones-with-milliseconds/